# Couldn't find function prototypes in a static library on Xcode (linker issue with library)

Tags: c, xcode, macos, api, dylib

I met with some linker issues when using static libraries.

Suppose I have two c files: example.c and main.c. I have example.c generated into a static library using: 
gcc -c example.c
ar -r libmylibrary.a example.o
Then, on Xcode, I add libmylibrary.a by following Target->Build Phases->Link Binary With Libraries, and the library is showing in the project. I also specify header search path and even library search path. It seems that's it. When I compile the project, the linker can find the function declaration in relative example.h file, however, it could not find the function prototypes defined in example.c file. Why this is happening? I have googled a lot and checked many relative questions on stack overflow, but nothing really helps so far...

BTW, if I use the command line like this:
gcc main.c -lmylibrary -L. -I. –o main
It will work. But I want it to work on Xcode, so that I can debug it conveniently.

Thanks in advance!